# How to determine using C# Reflection if a class is a WinRT type

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-runtime

Is there anyway at runtime to determine if a type is a WinRT class?  I.e. if its WinRT then behave in one way, if its not then behave in another?

Comment: are you trying to see if you are running inside winrt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2012/05/27/loading-winrt-types-via-reflection-in-windows-8.aspx

It looks like you can get the `AssemblyQualifiedName` and see if it contains `ContentType=WindowsRuntime`.